# First RewriteRule is being ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a Rewrite rule that detects if the request is coming from the user agent and process the URL and if not redirect to the index page. The First Rule does not seem to work and it goes directly to the second rule. I am not sure what I am doing wrong I added the flag [L] to stop the Rule after the condition has been met. It seems that the condition of the first rule is not being met, not certain where to start.

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  googlebot
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$ /  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/.*$
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following based on your shown samples only. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule  ^ /  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Hello, RavinderSingh13 I tried your method I am still having the same problem, I think it because I am using tomcat rewritevalve, the documentation says it is similar to apache Rewrite.

Comment: @user2491007, sorry I didn't get you are mentioning about tomcat rewrite? But we are talking about htaccess/apache rewrite/redirect here, could you please clarify more on this one, thank you.